# how to combine province data into one row country data in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my first question here. So I have COVID data in python, the distribution of COVID cases in several provinces in each country. 
What should I do if I want to make each country only have one data (one row), and drop the province column?

Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us a sample of what your data look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `groupby` date and country, apply `sum()` as the aggregate function, and `drop` the province column:

e.g. if you have a dataframe `df`, with columns `date`, `country`, `province`, and `cases`, then you should do:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['date', 'country']).sum().drop('province', axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi SimonR, it works very well! Thank you :)
But I have a problem that I did not mention it earlier, sorry.. 

I also want to keep the data reported daily. So I also have one 'date' column. I want each country only have one row (daily) data for each date. Can you please give me k another option to what should I do? Thank you again!

Comment: @mrsrw No problem - I've updated my answer to take the date into account. You just group by the date *and* the country (in that order)